# Access TextBlock Control in Source Page From Parent Frame in Metro Style App

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, frame

My Source Page

```
<Grid>   
    <TextBlock x:Name="TbHeader"/>
    <Frame x:Name="FrmPages" d:IsLocked="True"/>
</Grid>
```

My Source Page Codes

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            FrmPages.Navigate(typeof(Categories));
        }
```

This my parent Categories page codes

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //??? How can I change TbHeader.Text?
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly you are trying to change values in an XAML page that isn't being shown at the moment. If that's the case it doesn't really make sense.

If you would like to send data from a page to another depending on user input, you can use Navigate to send parameters, see [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx).